# MS Access 2010 subreports run fine, but main report freezes, only for user, not for dev. Why, and how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, crash, report, ms-access-2010, share

I am using MS Access 2010 on Windows 7, in a moderately locked down corporate environment. I have developed a report that calls several subreports, and one subform, which in turn has several embedded graphs. The various subentities pull data from multiple queries that build on other queries, some of which are parameterized. The two parameters (Year and Month values) are taken from a single form that includes buttons to preview and print the report. All data tables are local to the .accdb file; there is no server back end.

I developed the file locally, then copied it to a shared network folder and tested. Everything works as expected for me -- the report takes a few seconds to run, as the data work is admittedly a bit clunky, but it still displays in a timely fashion. I am in California, the shared folder is somewhere in the Midwest or South, and my coworker is in Texas. I asked coworker to open the file, enter values in the form, and run the report. He got a warning saying the file was read-only, but the form still ran, but the report locked up. Specifically, the report starts to run, the progress bar moves to about 1/3rd or 2/5ths across, then just stops. There is no error message given.

I had coworker force-close Access, deleted the lock file, gave coworker full permissions on the file, and had him try again. Same results, minus the read-only error. Entering values in the form and running the report directly, rather than using the buttons, gives the same result. I had him go through the other database objects, and all of the tables, base queries, subreports, and subform open "instantly", with the expected data and record counts. For some reason, though, bringing it all together just crashes Access every time.

Coworker was doing a screen share for the initial tests, so I know he was following directions correctly. We tried it without, in case the bandwidth was an issue, with no improvement.

I've tried searching variations on "ms access report locks/freezes/hangs" via Google and SO, and got a bunch of stuff about record-locking, which I think is not the issue here. If anyone can suggest better search terms, I'm game to try them.

The data used is confidential, so I'm reluctant to post code, but can work on sanitized versions if that's necessary for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file is locked in Read-Only, any calculations that are done which in any way write data to a table are not going to work.  I suggest you double check the security permissions the user has to the network folder.  That includes both the NTFS security and the shared folder security.

He needs write permission to the entire network folder (not just the database file) because Access will try to create the laccdb file and write to it within the network folder.  If he does not have write permissions on that folder access will not be able to edit the laccd file.

Comment: The .accdb file is not in read-only mode when he opens it now, and there are no actions in the report or base queries that write data to any tables.  

The folder permissions could be an issue. My understanding of the current rule set is that anyone can add or create files, but only owners can delete them. When he opens the .accdb, he is creating a new .laccdb of his own, so it seems like that shouldn't matter. It's worth a shot anyway, though, so I'll try that, thanks.   

Any idea why that would affect a parent report, but not a subreport?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you don't a compact and repair on it?  As long as the subreports open it should be working so chances are there is something wrong with that parent report.  You could try creating the parent report again and see if it's just a glitchy report.  I've had many "bugs" in Access over the years that defy logic and get fixed simply by recreating.

Comment: I haven't done either of those, but I'll give them a shot once I hear back from coworker. Still waiting on results of changing folder permissions. Thanks!

Comment: Changing the folder permissions seems to have done the trick. Thanks!